# MySQL / how to join a few rows to one

Tags: mysql

tbl1

```
+----+-----+
| id | key |
+----+-----+
| 1  | a   |
| 2  | b   |
| 3  | c   |
+----+-----+
```

tbl2

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id |  tbl1_id | value |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  |  1       | d     |
| 2  |  2       | e     |
| 3  |  2       | f     |
| 4  |  3       | g     |
| 5  |  3       | h     |
| 6  |  3       | i     |
+----+----------+-------+
```

How can I get this result?

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+
| id | key   | val0 | val1 | val2 |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
| 1  | a     | d    | NULL | NULL |
| 2  | b     | e    | f    | NULL |
| 3  | c     | g    | h    | i    |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Does the merged output have to be a table? will you know the maximum number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use table and column aliases:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, t0.value val0, t1.value val1, t2.value val2
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t0
ON a.id = t0.tbl1_id
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t1
ON a.id = t1.tbl1_id
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2
ON a.id = t2.tbl1_id
```

Comment: But I don't know the number of rows in the `tbl2` with the same `tbl1_id`

Comment: You did not say that in your question. I don't think that's possible, but maybe someone has got a better idea. Also, why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.key as title, b.value as val0, c.value as val1, d.value as val2
FROM tbl1 as a LEFT JOIN tbl2 as b ON a.id = b.tbl1_id 
               LEFT JOIN tbl2 as c ON a.id = c.tbl1_id 
               LEFT JOIN tbl2 as d ON a.id = d.tbl1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this, very well checked,

```
select distinct(t1.id) as id, t1.key as keyValue, 
(select t2.value from tbl2 t2 where t1.id=t2.tbl1_id and t2.id=(select min(t3.id)
from tbl2 t3 where t3.tbl1_id=t1.id) ) as val0,
(select t2.value from tbl2 t2 where t1.id=t2.tbl1_id and
t2.id=(select t3.id from tbl2 t3 where t3.tbl1_id=t1.id order by t3.id limit 1, 1) ) as val1,
(select t2.value from tbl2 t2 where t1.id=t2.tbl1_id and
t2.id=(select t3.id from tbl2 t3 where t3.tbl1_id=t1.id order by t3.id limit 2, 1) ) as val2
from tbl1 t1
```

[image]

Comment: If the maximum is three columns, it should not require so many subqueries. A few JOINs would suffice. However, it sounds like what they really need is something like a `crosstab` query, which is a totally different beast altogether...